# Error importing custom date fields when the day of month is above 12

Tags: civimember, joomla, date-preferences

Am new at this. I have created custom fields called Date Left and Date Reinstated in the dd/mm/yyyy format. When I try to import the data, days bigger than 12 are shown as errors, and up to 12 come in, but as mm/dd/yyyy. We have already imported into built-in date fields successfully using dd/mm/yyyy. Am using CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Joomla!3.4.1.

Comment: This might be a bug. I recently fixed a bug CRM-16625 in the importing of the birth_date and deceased_date of Contacts, and it sounds like the symptoms are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

In the CiviCRM engine the usuall date format is YYYYmmdd hhmm. You could try that date format. You could leave out the hhmm part.

Explenation of the format
- YYYY = year in four digits (2014)
- mm (months in 2 digits, 01 for january)
- dd (day of month in 2 digits e.g. 21)